# lost and found flutter app firebase problem

Tags: flutter, github

****i clone lost and found application from this url'https://github.com/xbrny/flutter_lost_and_found_pet.git' after this the application runs good in my emulator or even real device but it did not connects the firebase showing this errors ****

```
 I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): [DP] dp(1) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.reportNextDraw:10957 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3845 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 
I/SurfaceView( 4511): surfaceCreated 1 #8 io.flutter.view.FlutterView{331618f VFE...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2214}
I/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): Thread[5,tid=16217,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7e9f518000,peer=0x132456d8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 28
I/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): 
I/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): SIGSAVEPRF profile save
I/flutter ( 4511): [I] PostApi.fetchByTypeRaw (package:lost_found_pet_prototype/api/post_api.dart:47:33)
I/flutter ( 4511): -----------------------------------------------------------------------
I/flutter ( 4511): [I] PostApi.fetchByTypeRaw (package:lost_found_pet_prototype/api/post_api.dart:47:33)
I/flutter ( 4511): -----------------------------------------------------------------------
I/SurfaceView( 4511): surfaceChanged (1080,2214) 1 #8 io.flutter.view.FlutterView{331618f VFE...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2214}
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): [DP] dp(2) 1 android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface:1311 android.view.SurfaceView$1.onPreDraw:225 android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw:1124 
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): [DP] pdf(1) 1 android.view.SurfaceView.notifyDrawFinished:577 android.view.SurfaceView.performDrawFinished:564 android.view.SurfaceView.lambda$TWz4D2u33ZlAmRtgKzbqqDue3iM:0 
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): [DP] pd() Asnyc report
I/SurfaceView( 4511): setParentSpaceRectangle: useBLAST = false position = Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2214) frameNumber = 1 t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@24b2025
I/SurfaceView( 4511): applySurfaceTransforms: t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@24b2025 surfaceControl = Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype/com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype.MainActivity@331618f@0)/@0xf6625fa frame = 1
I/SurfaceView( 4511): applySurfaceTransforms: postScaleX = 1.0 postScaleY = 1.0
I/Gralloc4( 4511): mapper 4.x is not supported
W/Gralloc3( 4511): mapper 3.x is not supported
I/gralloc ( 4511): Arm Module v1.0
I/OpenGLRenderer( 4511): Davey! duration=3395ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=247680266318712, Vsync=247680649652030, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=247680665376575, AnimationStart=247680665392498, PerformTraversalsStart=247680665400152, DrawStart=247683354099880, SyncQueued=247683365596342, SyncStart=247683366611880, IssueDrawCommandsStart=247683368338726, SwapBuffers=247683652562188, FrameCompleted=247683662368342, DequeueBufferDuration=15779808, QueueBufferDuration=3851308, GpuCompleted=0, 
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): [DP] pdf(0) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$performDraw$1$ViewRootImpl:4668 android.view.-$$Lambda$ViewRootImpl$DJd0VUYJgsebcnSohO6h8zc_ONI.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): [DP] rdf()
I/Choreographer( 4511): Skipped 200 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/DynamiteModule( 4511): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ea67d83[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ea67d83[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
V/InputMethodManager( 4511): Starting input: tba=com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype ic=null mNaviBarColor -16711423 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager( 4511): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport( 4511): Input channel constructed: 'ClientS', fd=118
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ea67d83[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
V/InputMethodManager( 4511): Starting input: tba=com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype ic=null mNaviBarColor -16711423 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/DynamiteModule( 4511): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 4511): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[544085321024]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[544085321024]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[544085320928]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[544085320928]
I/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/TetheringManager( 4511): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype
D/ConnectivityManager( 4511): ConnectivityManager() mContext=io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication@edb51dc getOpPackageName()=com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype getBasePackageName()=com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype getPackageName()=com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype
I/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto( 4511): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 294 native methods...
W/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller( 4511): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): Background concurrent copying GC freed 75753(4401KB) AllocSpace objects, 43(2060KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4513KB/9026KB, paused 168us total 267.128ms
W/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (greylist, JNI, allowed)
W/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/d_pet_prototyp( 4511): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/Firestore( 4511): (23.0.1) [WatchStream]: (889ba2c) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Permission denied on resource project lost-and-found-pet., cause=null}.
W/Firestore( 4511): (23.0.1) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Permission denied on resource project lost-and-found-pet., cause=null}
W/Firestore( 4511): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[544085325536]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[544085325536]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[544085321792]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[544085321792]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[544085321120]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[544085321120]
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=(0,0,1080,2340) ci=(0,83,0,126) vi=(0,0,0,126) or=1
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): [DP] dp(1) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.reportNextDraw:10957 android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$1200:256 android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage:6101 
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[543837968960]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[543837968960]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0xb5a4c1c / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1115 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1820 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[546628036832]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[546628036832]
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2340) new=(0,0,1080,2340) req=(1080,2340)0 dur=13 res=0x1 s={true 544101502976} ch=false fn=8
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): [DP] pd() Asnyc report
W/libEGL  ( 4511): EGLNativeWindowType 0x7eaefa1010 disconnect failed
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): [DP] pdf(0) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$performDraw$1$ViewRootImpl:4668 android.view.-$$Lambda$ViewRootImpl$DJd0VUYJgsebcnSohO6h8zc_ONI.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): [DP] rdf()
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[543837968960]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[543837968960]
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ea67d83[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ea67d83[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
V/InputMethodManager( 4511): Starting input: tba=com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype ic=null mNaviBarColor -16711423 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager( 4511): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport( 4511): Input channel constructed: 'ClientS', fd=121
D/InputTransport( 4511): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=118
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 4511 view : com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): view is not EditText
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ea67d83[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
V/InputMethodManager( 4511): Starting input: tba=com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@bd257bf mNaviBarColor -16711423 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager( 4511): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport( 4511): Input channel constructed: 'ClientS', fd=118
D/InputTransport( 4511): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=121
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ea67d83[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ea67d83[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
V/InputMethodManager( 4511): Starting input: tba=com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@ac8f9d5 mNaviBarColor -16711423 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager( 4511): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport( 4511): Input channel constructed: 'ClientS', fd=121
D/InputTransport( 4511): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=118
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 1
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4511): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4511): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4511): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4511): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4511): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4511): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
D/InsetsSourceConsumer( 4511): setRequestedVisible: visible=true, type=13, host=com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype/com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype.MainActivity, from=android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.show:229 android.view.InsetsController.showDirectly:1437 android.view.InsetsController.controlAnimationUnchecked:1110 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1417 android.view.InsetsController.show:962 android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage:6146 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:106 android.os.Looper.loop:246 android.app.ActivityThread.main:8528 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke:-2 
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[543837968960]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[543837968960]
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 4511 view : com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): view is not EditText
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ea67d83[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ea67d83[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
V/InputMethodManager( 4511): Starting input: tba=com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@734d842 mNaviBarColor -16711423 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager( 4511): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager( 4511): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport( 4511): Input channel constructed: 'ClientS', fd=128
D/InputTransport( 4511): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=121
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4511): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 1
W/System  ( 4511): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out( 4511): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 4511): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/flutter ( 4511): PlatformException(FirebaseException, An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. ], null)
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 1
W/System  ( 4511): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out( 4511): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 4511): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/flutter ( 4511): PlatformException(FirebaseException, An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. ], null)
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[546628033952]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[546628033952]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[546628037024]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[546628037024]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[546628036928]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[546628036928]
I/ViewRootImpl@6f0a4a2[MainActivity]( 4511): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InsetsSourceConsumer( 4511): setRequestedVisible: visible=false, type=13, host=com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype/com.bitbani.lost_found_pet_prototype.MainActivity, from=android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.hide:236 android.view.ImeInsetsSourceConsumer.hide:101 android.view.InsetsController.hideDirectly:1430 android.view.InsetsController.controlAnimationUnchecked:1112 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1417 android.view.InsetsController.hide:984 android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage:6150 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:106 android.os.Looper.loop:246 android.app.ActivityThread.main:8528 
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject s[546628036928]
I/SurfaceControl( 4511): nativeRelease nativeObject e[546628036928]
D/InputTransport( 4511): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=128
I
```

**so please can you tell me how can I Connect it to the firebase also it always says your API key is invalid and i cant see where the invalid API is written in the app so please help its my final project defense of the first degree of university**

Answer (score 0):

For mobile and desktop, Firebase credentials are located in the `google-services.json` file that you download when you set-up Firebase for a platform. You can learn more about it [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android#generating-a-firebase-project-configuration-file).